# Generic Programming Concepts as Replacement for Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, generic-programming

I am working on a piece of code where several elements can have an orientation, meaning that their spatial position is relative to a reference frame.

I could create an abstract base class called `OrientedObject`, and then a collection of algorithms acting on instances of this class.

I could also define my own `oriented` concept, and write generic algorithms acting on types which fulfill the concept (similar to the design of the [Boost Geometry Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/concepts.html)).

According to the Boost [*Generic Programming Techniques*](http://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html) page:

> A concept is a set of requirements consisting of valid expressions,
>   associated types, invariants, and complexity guarantees. A type that
>   satisfies the requirements is said to model the concept. A concept can
>   extend the requirements of another concept, which is called
>   refinement.

Accordingly, the `oriented` concept could be defined as a collection of necessary types (such as vectors), valid operations (such as `rotate`), etc.

It seems to me that if inheritance models the **is a** relationship, and a concept **defines** whether something **is a**, then a concept represents a form of inheritance, which happens to be more practical and extensible (along the lines of *duck typing*) if also more intellectually complex to define properly.

Now, inheritance is necessary if one wants to create a container of related types. For example, I could not create a container of oriented types unless they belong to the same base class.

So, I am having a hard time deciding whether defining my concepts in terms of `concept` or in terms of inheritance (and I cannot think of any other form).

Can you offer any guidance?

Comment: Use polymorphic inheritance if and only if you need to manage a heterogeneous collection of objects whose types you only know at runtime, but cannot know statically. Otherwise, you can keep all your types separate statically.

Comment: @KerrekSB I need to keep one single collection of these guys into a very specific part of my program... it seems that only because of that I will have to rely on inheritance... I would have liked to use concepts... oh well...

Comment: @KerrekSB: Using dynamic polymorphism can also avoid binary bloat (although the compiler can sometimes coalesce identical implementations).

Comment: @Escualo: You can use type erasure to provide a dynamically polymorphic interface on top of a statically polymorphic one, allowing the use of either at appropriate places in the program.